# What's wrong with this presto query?

Tags: mysql, presto, trino

`select * from table1 where created_at  > date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 day)`

I'm trying to get everything created within the last day, but I'm getting this error:
mismatched input '1'. Expecting: ',', "
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The very specific error is about interval syntax:  the number should be quoted: `interval '1' day` .

Answer (score 2):

`date_sub` is a MySQL specific function. In Presto there are other [time interval functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#interval-functions). I suppose your query should be something like that:

```
select * from table1 where created_at > date_add('day', -1, now());
```

However I don't have any Presto instance to test it.